# Translate Mathematica Output to Latex type font

Tags: functions, latex, inequalities, slot

In solving the inequality $2d^2\ge -(2(1+d)+\frac{4d^3}{1-d})(d-1)$, Mathematica returns something using Slots and Functions:

```
In:= Reduce[2 d^2 >= -((2*(1 + d) + ((4 d^3)/(1 - d)))*(d - 1)), d]
Out= d <= Root[1 - 2 #1^2 + 2 #1^3 &, 1]
```

How do I translate this output to a Latex type font, as I have written in the beginning of this question? I know I start with $d\le \sqrt[1]{1-}$, but I'm really thrown off by the `#` and `&`. Could someone put me on the right track?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is. Are you asking what `Root[...]` _means_? Or are you asking how to write `Root[...]` in LaTeX so that it will look the same as in Mathematica?

Comment: `Root`, `#` and `&` are foreign to me, although I am reading up on Slots and Functions.

Comment: Slots and functions are less important, please read the docs of `Root`. `Root[1 - 2 #1^2 + 2 #1^3 &, 1]` indicates the 1st root of the polynomial $1-2x^2+2x^3$.

Comment: @kglr answered this in another question of yours but to add it to this thread, consider using the function ToRadicals.  It gives a pretty printed version of this "d <= 1/3 (1 - 2^(2/3)/(23 - 3 Sqrt[57])^(1/3) - (23 - 3 Sqrt[57])^(
    1/3)/2^(2/3))".  ToRadicals is a recommended "See also" function of Root, so you could get there by reviewing that part of the documentation too.